# How to add dynamic value from useMemo function into tests with React Testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a set of radio buttons with some dates on for a user to select when wanting to download a report. These dates change based on what time of year it is, they are within an array and sorted based on oldest to most recent date, all within a useMemo function.

So the 0th index of the array is consistently changing, and I am trying to run some tests with React testing library but am unsure how to account for this changing array.

The default date set in the state is the 0th index, so if nothing is selected then that is the default selected date.

This is my useMemo function and radio buttons, along with useEffect to set the default state:

```
const StockReportModal = (props) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const { close, onDownloadStockReport } = props;

    const [baseDate, setBaseDate] = useState("");

    const datesArrayFormatted = useMemo(() => {
        const year = new Date().getFullYear();
        let datesArray = [new Date(year, 2, 31), new Date(year, 5, 30), new Date(year, 8, 30), new Date(year, 11, 31)];

        datesArray.forEach((date) => {
            if (date > new Date()) {
                date.setFullYear(year - 1);
            }
        });

        datesArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });

        return datesArray;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        let date;
        date = formatUTCEndDate(datesArrayFormatted[0]);
        setBaseDate({ date: moment(date).toISOString() });
    }, [datesArrayFormatted]);

    const DateOptions = useMemo(
        () => ({
            first: "first",
            second: "second",
            third: "third",
            fourth: "fourth",
            custom: "custom",
        }),
        []
    );

    const dateOptions = useMemo(() => {
        return [
            {
                value: DateOptions.first,
                description: moment(datesArrayFormatted[0]).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
            },
            {
                value: DateOptions.second,
                description: moment(datesArrayFormatted[1]).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
            },
            {
                value: DateOptions.third,
                description: moment(datesArrayFormatted[2]).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
            },
            {
                value: DateOptions.fourth,
                description: moment(datesArrayFormatted[3]).format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
            },

            { value: DateOptions.custom, description: "Custom"
        ];
    }, [DateOptions, t, datesArrayFormatted]);

    const onDateChange = useCallback(
        (val) => {
            let date;
            switch (val) {
                case DateOptions.first:
                    date = formatUTCEndDate(datesArrayFormatted[0]);
                    setBaseDate({ date: moment(date).toISOString() });
                    break;
                case DateOptions.second:
                    date = formatUTCEndDate(datesArrayFormatted[1]);
                    setBaseDate({ date: moment(date).toISOString() });
                    break;
                case DateOptions.third:
                    date = formatUTCEndDate(datesArrayFormatted[2]);
                    setBaseDate({ date: moment(date).toISOString() });
                    break;
                case DateOptions.fourth:
                    date = formatUTCEndDate(datesArrayFormatted[3]);
                    setBaseDate({ date: moment(date).toISOString() });
                    break;
                case DateOptions.custom:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            setDateValue(val);
        },
        [DateOptions, setBaseDate, setDateValue, datesArrayFormatted]
    );

    const onFileChange = useCallback(
        (val) => {
            setFileValue(val);
        },
        [setFileValue]
    );

    const onDownloadReport = useCallback(() => {
        onDownloadStockReport({
            dates: { date: baseDate.date },
            file_type: fileValue,
            service: ReportTypes.stocks,
        });
        close();
    }, [close, baseDate, fileValue, onDownloadStockReport]);

    return (
        <Modal close={close} className={"report-stock-modal"}>
            <ModalBody>
                <Heading align={"center"} level={"2"}>
                    Reports
                </Heading>
                <Radio options={dateOptions} testId={"stock-date-option"} value={dateValue} onChange={onDateChange} />
            </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
    );
};

export default StockReportModal;
```

And this is my test in my test file:

```
describe("StockReportModal test", () => {
    const defaultDate = formatUTCEndDate(moment(datesArrayFormatted[0]).format("MMMM Do YYYY").toISOString());
    const defaultFileType = "pdf";

    const sampleDate = "20/01/2020";
    it("should render with initial state", () => {
        render(<StockReportModal {...props} />);
        const downloadBtn = screen.getByTestId("stock-save");
        fireEvent.click(downloadBtn);

        expect(props.onDownloadStockReport).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(props.onDownloadStockReport).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            dates: { date: defaultDate },
            file_type: defaultFileType,
            service: ReportTypes.stocks,
        });

        expect(props.close).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

I'm not sure how to add the memoized value on the defaultDate variable in my test file, I tried adding the useMemo function in my test file but receive a Hooks error, is there a simple way to do this?

I'm fairly new to testing.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: if your memoized value isn't dependent on anything from inside your component, define it outside the component and export it, so you can import it directly in your test file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to predict values in radio group so test could pick first option specifically.

I see 3 options here:

1. Mock system time. For unit test we mock a lot of things, mocking system time is legit. How? [`jest.useFakeTimers`  + `jest.setSystemTime`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestsetsystemtimenow-number--date). Then you can hard-code in your test selector for the first option and it always be the first.
2. Generate date in your test by implementing partially logic from this `useMemo` in your test suite(I don't recommend this, test which repeats code under testing is... weird and not that stable)
3. Assign meaningful `test-id` attribute for the first entry. E.g. `test-id="earliest-date"` and use it for `getByTestId()`(sounds like a tricky workaround and it is)

I recommend going with the first.

PS and you don't need `useMemo` in your test code in any way. It's used inside React component's code either for performance reason or to keep referential equality of some JS object which will make difference only to other React component. You test will work the same, whether there is `useMemo` in component or all those dates are calculated on each re-render.